# Connect to DB with Linked Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to connect to an SQL Server using Access, like Linked Tables. However, the DB is saved on a shared folder on a shared drive. When I created a data source, it is machine specific, so users on other machines can't access it.

Is there a way to connect tables from the SQL Server using a connection string, like you can with pass-through queries?

Comment: Are you building a front end then? If so you could do it by writing vba code and using connection strings in that instead of odbc...

Comment: I think this has been answered already:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023053/front-end-access-alternative-relying-on-odbc-connection

Answer (score 3):

You could use a DSN when first creating ODBC links to SQL Server.  Then later change the `.Connect` property of the link `TableDef`s to use DSN-less connections.  (See [Using DSN-Less Connections](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html) for details.)

Here is an example of a working ODBC link to SQL Server which doesn't depend on a DSN.  Note the `.Connect` property is a single text string, and I split that string on the semicolons to make it easier to read.

```
? Replace(CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblFoo").Connect, ";", ";" & vbCrLf)
ODBC;
DRIVER=SQL Server;
SERVER=HP64\SQLEXPRESS;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;
DATABASE=testbed
```

Or you could use the [DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx) with a DSN-less connection string to create the link.

Either way, your users would not need a DSN to use those linked tables.